# I want to load a php include file using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to load a php include file using jquery, ie., should reload.  I have the german language loaded below

```
<div id="lang_files"><? include('lang-de.php'); ?></div>
```

Now I want to load the french language using

```
    $('#lang12').bind('click',function(){

        ('#lang_files').load('lang-fr.php');
 });
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Based on your question: Who does prevent you from doing so?

Comment: is this a localization for dynamic-php output, or for fixed placeholders in your markup? ... should the translation be used from ui-only or from php ...?? ... more information needed!

Comment: Well it does, but the include file does not load

Comment: @andreas
When the page loads it loads german by default, but when someone clicks on french it must change to french without page reload

Comment: Without page reload ??? You then want to rewrite all your text on the webpage via javascript ? Is it really a good idea ?

Comment: @Guillaume mmm, why not. As long as he has a non-Javascript fallback, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Jean what error messages do you get?

Comment: @pekka Nothing, if I recall the value in #lang_files via alert it shows me the fr lang file, but it does not load the file.   I have also tried .load()

Comment: @Jean can you post an example of what the language file looks like? Have you inspected the element with firebug to see whether anything gets loaded, perhaps invisibly?

Comment: @pekka done it with alert by calling the val() using the #id, but checking on the source code it should the default german lang file

Comment: @Jean please show an example of a language file. Also, Firebug will tell you more than an alert().

Comment: the php file for english is

<? $about = "About"; ?>

and like wise for french and german

Comment: You cannot run PHP in your browser. So you either need to run it on the server and return a file containing HTML or change the format of your file to HTML. Both solutions need you to put the HTML into an element (ie your `<div id="lang_files">`). A complete different solution is to modify the file so it contains id-string pairs and use my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `id` attribute on every element you need to be multi-lingual, you can use a language file with id-string pairs to replace all texts. To get this language file you could use Ajax ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) a bit to get enough examples how that works).

Pseudo code to describe the step to change the language:

```
response = doAjaxRequest(language);
array = convertResponseToPairs(response);
for each element in array {
  e = getElementById(element.id);
  e.innerText = element.text;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the number of elements on the page, this is possibly slower and more complex than what the OP has now: At the moment, he seems to have monolithic blocks of content. I would tend to stay with that and try to get that working. This solution is good for scenarios where word-for-word translation is needed.

Comment: @Jean: yes, in JavaScript you have to perform the actions described in the pseudo code block. As Pekka mentioned, it might be slow to replace one element at a time.

Comment: @Pekka, If there is just one block which needs to change its language, I agree. But I was under the impression that the complete page needed the translation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the lang-xx.php is independent from the containing page, (e.g. it uses no variables defined out of it), we can do this like so:

```
$('#lang12').click(function(){
    $.get("lang-fr.php",
        function(data){
            $('#lang_files').html(data);
        });
});
```